# How to generate similarity scores heatmap from multiple gene lists in R

Tags: r, loops, heatmap, bioinformatics

**Problem**
I have a melted dataframe of 19 different tumor types, each with associated marker genes. I want to visualize the similarity between tumor types to see how they cluster. I have a plan to attack this problem, but it seems like there **should** be an easier way.

**Dummy Data**

```r
>df <- data.frame(tumor_type = c("tumor1", "tumor1", "tumor1", "tumor2", "tumor2", "tumor3", "tumor4", "tumor4"), genes = c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC", "geneA", "geneD", "geneD", "geneA", "geneD"))

>df
tumor_type  genes
tumor1      geneA
tumor1      geneB
tumor1      geneC
tumor2      geneA
tumor2      geneD
tumor3      geneD
tumor4      geneA
tumor4      geneD
```

**Proposed solution**
1) Break melted dataframe into individual tumor lists
2) Calculate pairwise similarity scores between all combinations of tumors. I'll have to do some kind of for loop using (intersect(tumor1, tumor2)/(intersect(tumor1, tumor2) + setdiff(tumor1, tumor2) + setdiff(tumor2, tumor1))*100.
Should get a matrix like:

```r
>dfmatrix
       tumor1   tumor2   tumor3   tumor4
tumor1    100       25        0       25
tumor2     25      100       50       50
tumor3      0       50      100       50  
tumor4     25       50       50      100
```

3) I'll then do a standard heatmap

I will need help figuring out the individual components (like how to do the loop to do all pairwise comparisons), but I thought I should start at a higher level to make sure that my thinking about this process is correct before asking a bunch of different questions on the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simplified solution, maybe just for exploring the data. You simplify the problem to asking which gene is associated with each tumour, in a binary manner:

```
table(df$tumor_type,df$genes)
         geneA geneB geneC geneD
  tumor1     1     1     1     0
  tumor2     1     0     0     1
  tumor3     0     0     0     1
  tumor4     1     0     0     1
```

Then we can use a pairwise distance using dist:

```
D = dist(table(df$tumor_type,df$genes),method="binary")
       tumor1 tumor2 tumor3
tumor2   0.75              
tumor3   1.00   0.50       
tumor4   0.75   0.00   0.50
```

Or if you prefer other measurements, you can do:

```
library(ade4)
D = dist.binary(unclass(table(df$tumor_type,df$genes)),method=1)
```

Then just visualize 1-distance

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(1-as.matrix(D))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "19 different tumor types" can be represented as 19 samples, so that you can create a n_genes x 19 expression matrix, you could use `dcast` to generate the matrix, then generate pairwise correlation heatmaps.

You may have to think about ways to deal with missing data to get appropriate similarity scores.

Assuming a complete matrix, you could just use the dist function, for example:

```r
library(data.table)
library(pheatmap)

# mock data
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(
    stats::runif(1000, 3, 14),
    nrow = 100,
    ncol = 10,
    dimnames = list(paste0("gene", 1:100), paste0("Sample", 1:10))
)
modmat <- base::sample(1:100, 30)
mat[modmat, 1:5] <- mat[modmat, 1:5] + stats::runif(150, 4, 6)
MAT <- melt(data.table(mat, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.vars = "rn")
# MAT would correspond to your melted data.frame, after setDT(your.df)

mat <- as.matrix(dcast(MAT, rn ~ variable), rownames = 1)
cmat <- as.matrix(dist(t(mat), diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))

pheatmap(cmat)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>