# Plotting jaccard index with values inside the heatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

Im trying to calculate and plotting the jaccard index the same

My dummy data and code

```
df <- data.frame(tumor_type = c("tumor1", "tumor1", "tumor1", "tumor2", "tumor2", "tumor3", "tumor4", "tumor4"), genes = c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC", "geneA", "geneD", "geneD", "geneA", "geneD"))

D1 <- vegdist(unclass(table(df$tumor_type,df$genes)), method = "jaccard")

pheatmap(1-as.matrix(D1))
```

I get this
[image: image i get]

For my actual data I tried an online tool i get this

[image]

My objective is to get similar such as showing the element present in each sub-type and their jacard score

Small subset of my data

```
structure(list(Comparison = c("M0_vs_M1", "M0_vs_M1", "M0_vs_M1", 
"M0_vs_M1", "M0_vs_M1", "M0_vs_M1", "M4_vs_M5", "M4_vs_M5", "M4_vs_M5", 
"M4_vs_M5", "M4_vs_M5", "M4_vs_M5"), Term = c("GO:0042742", "GO:0009617", 
"GO:0006959", "GO:0006956", "GO:0006958", "GO:0002455", "GO:0048863", 
"GO:0048864", "GO:0001667", "GO:0048483", "GO:0051129", "GO:0010977"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3266L, 3267L, 3268L, 
3269L, 3270L, 3271L), class = "data.frame")
```

My output

[image: myoutput]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add values by using `display_numbers = ...` argument inside `pheatmap()`.

```
pheatmap(1-as.matrix(D1), display_numbers = 1-as.matrix(D1))
```

[image]

```
D2 <- matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
D2[lower.tri(D2)] <- 1 - D1
D2 <- matrix(D2 %+% t(D2), ncol = 4)
diag(D2) <- NA
D2
D3 <- matrix(rep(10, 16), ncol = 4)
diag(D3) <- NA
D3

D4 <- matrix(paste(D3,D2, sep ="\n"), ncol = 4)
diag(D4) <- ""
pheatmap(1-as.matrix(D1), display_numbers = D4)
```

[image]

Comment: these are the jaccard score..can u show the intersection into the box? as shown in the second figure where they show both the index score and the set size

Comment: @PesKchan Well, can you provide code to make set size matrix?

Comment: actually  i m not sure how this does https://molbiotools.com/listcompare.php this is the site where I had to run multiple intersection so i came across this there they show have a look and see if you can know how they

Comment: `intersect(tumor1, tumor2)/(intersect(tumor1, tumor2) + setdiff(tumor1, tumor2) + setdiff(tumor2, tumor1))*100` this is the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122882/how-to-generate-similarity-scores-heatmap-from-multiple-gene-lists-in-r

Comment: I was able to use that answer to get to this extent where i get the element in the individual list `mat1 <- as.matrix(dcast(df, Comparison ~ Comparison), rownames = 1)
` but not in the intersection

Comment: @PesKchan I add the code for print both set size and index. `D3` is matrix for set size, what is dummy now. You should change that values

Comment: `D3 is matrix for set size` a little doubt conceptual ..you set it for 4 ..what should i do for 15 ? that part im unable to get it.. I mean the 10 part in the code do i set it 10?

Comment: @PesKchan Let's say there are tumor 1~15, just change that every `4`  to `15` and `16` to `225`

Comment: the 10 part? which is the set element and intersection size...you have fixed which should be different for different  element